# Ascend "by", should it be ablative?

Tags: grammar-choice

In music, a "comma" is a rough unit of intonation. If I were to refer to a refrain which had globally ascended a comma compared to the previous time it occurred, does it make sense that it would function as an ablative of agent with *ascendo*, assuming that is the verb I would like to use? So *iteratio commate superiore ascendit quam prius*. I could imagine it also ascending "to a higher comma"...not sure, my gut seems to say ablative, but it feels awkward. Any insights? It would be comparable to a statement like *the water level "ascends" a meter higher than it was before"*.